# CABAC: Looking for test patterns

Tags: h.264, video-encoding, hevc, h.265

I'd like to test (black-box testing) an H.265 CABAC module written in C and I'm looking for some test patterns (if they exist).

The way I see such a test pattern:

- an input array
- some information for each array value (to know what context model I need to use in the encoding process)
- the expected output (binary)

Does anyone have knowledge of such a thing?

Comment: Use the reference SW for HEVC available from https://hevc.hhi.fraunhofer.de/svn/svn_HEVCSoftware/ Using that you can dump the input to the cabac-module to file and use that as input for your testing.